# How Jquery/Javascript behave on dynamic content updation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I was assigned to task where I have to make a jquery method which will call an ajax.
When response comes successfully from ajax request, I put that response html code after the calling elements parent tr.

In my response HTML I have written a jquery toggle function to slide down some information and change the text to plus to minus and vice versa.

But it worked weirdly, Now when added **live** to it then it worked perfectly.

I am using jquery 1.7.

Here is my code

this is for ajax in the main page

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
                            $(document).ready(function() {


                                $('.loadCampaign').click(function(e) {
                                    //e.preventDefault();
                                    var campId = $(this).attr('id');
                                    var arr = campId.split('_');
                                    campId = arr[1];
                                    var parentTrId = '#campaign_tr_' + campId;
                                    var cBodyClass = campId + '-cBody';
                                    var body = $('.' + 'trView_' + campId);

                                    if (body.length) {
                                        body.remove();
                                    } else {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            //dataType: "json",
                                            url: '{{config.adminUrl}}/campaign/loadCamapaignDetails',
                                            data: {'id': campId},
                                            type: 'get',
                                            success: function(jd)
                                            {
                                                if (jd !== '0') {
                                                    $(parentTrId).after('<tr id="view_content" class="even ' + cBodyClass + ' trView_' + campId + '">' + jd + '</tr>');
                                                } else {
                                                    alert('Your request can not be process! Please refresh the page and try again')
                                                }

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                });
                            });

</script>
```

Now this one is written in ajax response:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function showHideDate(id){
    $('#showHideDate_'+id).toggle(function(){
        $("#bookedDates_"+id).slideDown(
         function(){
           $('#showHideDate_'+id).text("-")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $("#bookedDates_"+id).slideUp(
       function(){
           $('#showHideDate_'+id).text("+")
       }
       );
   });     
};

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.plus').live('click',function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var idArr=id.split('_');
        id=idArr[1];
        //alert(id);
        showHideDate(id);
});


});

</script>
```

Now I am not clear that when remove that **live** and wirte it as `.click(function()` then why its not working?

I am not that much sound in Javasript/jquery

Comment: This is the exact point of `live`.

Comment: @David hedlund  Why live!! what is binding in jquery??

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: are you obliged to use 1.7 ?

Comment: @steo I just went with the existing project code thats y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) generates so called delegate event handler, which hooks it to elements in question + dynamically generated elements after site is first loaded. [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) does just the elements that are there since the beginning.

However, [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the deprecated point!! Can you please suggest me some links where I can read about event handlers of jquery

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary The same site I linked the `live`, `click` and `on` events from. So http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 1):

You should make `jQuery` api documentation your bible as far from now.

As of **jquery 1.8+**

You gotta use `.on()` to `bind` and `delegate` `events` .

```
.on()
```

is very important, overall for it `delegate` feature ,that is fundamental in case like appending or  inserting dynamic content  into your markup.

check it out here :
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

To understand the point of "live", let's take this example:
with this page:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div class=".myDiv"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Simple page right ?
If you use a block view like the one below:

```
+--------
|<body>
|   +----
|   |<div class="myDiv">
```

When you attach events to elements in the html , they litterally "Attach" themselves:
Lets take for example a click event on .myDiv

- normal click : `$('.myDiv').click(function(){//do something})`
- live click (deprecated) : `$('.myDiv').live('click', function(){//do something})`
- on (best way): `$(body).on('click','.myDiv', function(){// do something})`

They represent themselves like this:

```
+--------+
|<body>  <- Event Click on .mydiv ex: ( $('.myDiv').live('click')
|                                    Or $(body).on('click','.mydiv'))
|
|
|    +--------
|    | <div .myDiv> <- Event Click ex: ($('.myDiv').click())
|    |
|    +--------
|
+----------
```

Now you can see that when you use .live, the event attaches itself at the root element of your html page (it's document () usually).

If you add (Via ajax) a new html element:

```
+--------+
|<body>  <- Event Click on .mydiv ex: ( $('.myDiv').live('click')
|                                    Or $(body).on('click','.mydiv'))
|
|
|    +--------
|    | <div .myDiv> <- Event Click ex: ($('.myDiv').click())
|    |
|    +--------
|       vv
|    +--------
|    | <div .myDiv> -> Yay ! I'm new from ajax
|    |
|    +--------
|
+----------
```

If you had written your "click" function on your .myDiv(s) before the new element is fetched from Ajax, the new element will not have a Event Handler on it, and will do nothing
That's because an event is usually "attached" to (an) HTML element(s)

but as you can see , on the root element  in my example, the events live and on, are still there.
Basically, doing "live" or "on" (which is more precise), will listen to all clicks on the page and when a click happen, it will figure out if the area clicked is the one you want and thus trigger your function,
For as long as the  tag is here or as long as it listen to those clicks.
that's what they mean by delegation of events.

The best practice with "on" is to attach the events to an element static which a is direct parent of your dynamically fetched HTML, so that only the area that matters listen to your events.

Hope that helped