# Button click event based on class isn't being fired on button that is dynamically created.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with dynamically created rows. Each row has a link button that you click on to delete that row. This is the click function here:

```
$(".deleteButton").on('click', function(){
    console.log("Delete Hit");
    var successful = deleteEntry($(this).attr('id'));
    if(successful == true){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }else{
        alert("Delete Unsuccessful.");
    }
});
```

Some of the buttons are created with one function when the page first loads. Those work, but this other function seems to create a button with the right classes for the event to fire. It creates a link like this.

```
<a class="deleteButton dButton" href="#">
```

while the one that works right creates a link like this,

```
<a href='#' class='deleteButton'>
```

I have checked in the inspector and it says that the button has the class deleteButton, which is required to fire the event, but it seems to be ignoring it entirely. The Delete Hit never shows in the console.This has really confused me for some time, and I'd appreciate the help anyone can give.

Comment: From the docs: `Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.` - how do dynamic elements fit that description? Read about delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegated events for elements that doesn't exist on DOM when you bind event handler

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function(){...}
```

Where `document` can be any `.deleteButton` container that exists at handler bind time.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I guess what got me is the fact that to me it seemed that they where both dynamically created. But I guess since the function that created the first ones was called before the click event was declared it worked for them.

Answer (score 0):

The existing buttons get their event handlers on page load, but the new button is added to the DOM afterwards. You would have to update your JavaScript code, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function(){
    console.log("Delete Hit");
    var successful = deleteEntry($(this).attr('id'));
    if(successful == true){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }else{
        alert("Delete Unsuccessful.");
    }
});
```

Find more info in the jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events.

Comment: You don't need the quotes around `document`

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate your events.

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function(e){
    //do something
});
```

here is a similar post where I explain the differences between bind live and "on".
[How Jquery/Javascript behave on dynamic content updation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720650/how-jquery-javascript-behave-on-dynamic-content-updation/17722047#17722047)